# JQuery Toggle works on first click but not again (as expected)

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, show-hide

I'm creating a div which is shown(toggled) by clicking on another element.

It should be shown when i click an anchor(`#toggle-contents`) and hidden if i click on the same anchor or somewhere else in the document.

I'm following the code in this how-to: [Creative overlay/popup with jQuery](http://pure-essence.net/2010/01/15/creative-overlaypopup-with-jquery/).

It is currently working for the first time it's clicked, - but then it gets displayed and hidden shortly afterwards.

The markup:

```
<div id="block-header">
    <a id="trigger-contents">Toggle</a>
  </div>
  <div id="block-contents">
  </div>
```

The javascript:

```
function registerToggleDiv( trigger, toggle )
{
  $( '#' + trigger ).click(function() 
    {
      $( '#' + toggle ).toggle(function() 
      {
        console.log('toggle');
        $(document).click(function(event) 
        {
          if ( !($(event.target).is('#' + toggle ) || 
                $(event.target).parents('#' + toggle ).length || 
                $(event.target).is( '#' + trigger ))) 
          {
            console.log('toggle hide');
            $('#' + toggle ).hide(500);
          }
        });
      });
    });
}
registerToggleDiv( 'trigger-contents', 'block-contents' );
```

I tried to find to error comparing to other toggle-questions here but didn't find any hint.

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: what are you trying to do why not just use: $('#'+ toggle).toggle(); this line $('#' + toggle ).hide(500); might be hiding it.

Comment: How/Where you initial `toggle ` variable ?

Comment: To summarize what your code does: every time 'toggle' is toggled, it adds a .click event handler to the document, then hides the 'toggle' element. Please specify what you WANT it to do, as it is, your desire is a bit confusing.

Comment: Thank you for your comments - i updated my question an hopefully it's more meaningful now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on `trigger`, propagation will happen and document `onclick` will fire.

You are binding to document `onclick` event :

```
$('#' + toggle ).hide(500);
```

you should stop propagation in clicked element to prevent document click as below :

```
$( '#' + trigger).click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```